# dnf keeps showing "European Southern Observatory RPM repository" message

Tags: fedora, dnf

Whenever I use `sudo dnf` to install a package on Fedora 36, this message always appears:

```
European Southern Observatory RPM repository fo 0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:06    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'esorepo':
  - Curl error (9): Access denied to remote resource for ftp://ftp.eso.org/pub/dfs/pipelines/repositories/stable/fedora/36/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Server denied you to change to the given directory]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'esorepo': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
Ignoring repositories: esorepo
```

After, the terminal output seems normal and shows output relevant to the package I am about to install, but this previous message is annoying. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to its documentation](https://www.eso.org/sci/software/pipelines/installation/rpm.html), the `esorepo` repository is currently only supported for Fedora 33 to 35, CentOS 7 and Scientific Linux 7 (SL 7) for 64 bits architectures.

So you should disable or remove the `esorepo` repository from your package manager configuration, since it is going to be useless to you until support for Fedora 36 is added to the repository.

To disable the `esorepo` repository (so you can re-enable it later, if/when Fedora 36 support is added):

```
sudo dnf config-manager --disable esorepo
```

To remove the definition of the `esorepo` repository, look into your `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory, find the `.repo` file that defines the `esorepo` repository, and remove it. (If `rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d/esorepo.repo` indicates the repository file is installed by a particular RPM package, you might want to uninstall that RPM package instead, to achieve the same effect more cleanly.)

**At your own risk**, you might try editing the `/etc/yum.repos.d/esorepo.repo` file to refer to the packages of Fedora 35 instead, as the `ftp.eso.org` server simply does not yet have a directory for Fedora 36.

There are two lines in the `esorepo.repo` file you would need to change:

```
baseurl=ftp://ftp.eso.org/pub/dfs/pipelines/repositories/stable/fedora/$releasever/$basearch
```

and

```
gpgkey=ftp://ftp.eso.org/pub/dfs/pipelines/repositories/stable/fedora/$releasever/$basearch/eso-pubkey.asc
```

On both of those lines, you would need to replace the `$releasever` with `35`. This will cause the package manager to look into esorepo's Fedora 35 directory, instead of trying to access the non-existent directory for Fedora 36.

You must then be careful to only install any packages from `esorepo` into the `fedora-toolbox-35` container only (like you mentioned in the comments), not into the Fedora 36 host OS.

Comment: I see, but I actually need `esorepo` for my research. I have installed and been using it in a toolbox `toolbox enter fedora-toolbox-35`

Comment: The fact that you actually use the `esorepo` in a toolbox container based on Fedora 35 is important information. You might want to edit your question to add that fact in, in case someone else can suggest a better way for that specific situation; otherwise, see my edit above.